# How to restore the git pull request made with numerous unwanted changes due to ends of lines

Tags: git, commit, git-history

There are methods how to prevent the unwanted changes in files due to different ends of lines. But how can I repair the pull request that already contents the numerous unwanted changes and, simultaneously, some useful and needed changes?

I check file after file and checkout the current /develop branch state for them. But that suppose too much work.

I can again branch the state before the branching and commit only needed files into that branch. Again, check of all files is supposed.

I can't separate by rebasing (removing the bad commit), because the commits included both useful and excessive changes. There is not separate commit for ends of lines.

```
git diff --ignore-space-at-eol
```

can show me only significant differences. But can I say to git to merge only the lines from this diff?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/

Comment: Your best bet might be to just sort out your line endings from this point going forward.  Make sure that all developers use the same convention.